# .NET Compact Framework 2.0 AutoSize Label

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, custom-controls

I trying to make a Control that inherits from System.Windows.Form.Label that can resize to fit its text.

I'm trying to override OnTextChanged method to use System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString to know the new size of the control, but I don't know how to obtain Graphics on OnTextChanged method?

Any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Control.CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method.  The documentation says it's supported on the compact framework.

```
Graphics graphics = myLabel.CreateGraphics();
```

Comment: It throws a NotSupportedException. Maybe it doesn't implemented on .Net Compact Framework 2.0's label object.